# Python for loop iterate in stepsize 3

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This might be a simple problem, but I seem to have spent too much time on it... My problem consist of creating a for loop that iterates through a list.

For each iteration should three elements be extracted => those being i, i+1 and i+2.  But for some reason am I not able to iterate through the list without getting out of index or something like that?..

The way I currently iterating is as so:

```
        for i in xrange(0,len(data_train_output_full)-1,3):
            data = np.array([data_train_output_full[i],data_train_output_full[i+1],data_train_output_full[i+2]])
            data_train_output.append(data)
```

And the error message I am getting is:

```
IndexError: index 278 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 278
```

Comment: `for i in xrange(0,len(data_train_output_full)-1,3):` will stop correctly, but you still have `data_train_output_full[i+1],data_train_output_full[i+2]` in the loop i.e. `i+1` and `i+2` indices. Perhaps you want `for i in xrange(0,len(data_train_output_full)-3,3):`

Comment: What is the length of `data_train_output_full`? It's hard to give a definitive answer without knowing that.

Comment: @roganjosh: I think you only need `len(...)-2`, not `-3`. The last element in the `xrange` is never yielded, so the last `i` value will be `len(...)-3`, which you can safely add two to.

Comment: Welll there are different list with different length.. The last one has 278 entries, and end at  i 276, in which the error occur.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because the `stop` value you're giving to `xrange` is not correct. Since you're checking two indexes after the highest one provided by `xrange`, you need to subtract two from the length of the input sequence (`len(data_train_output_full)-2` instead of `-1`).

There's also an [`itertools` recipe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) for this kind of iteration:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

If your list might be uneven and you want the last values to be skipped instead of padded, you can use `itertools.izip` instead of `itertools.izip_longest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a quick generator for this, using `itertools.islice` ideally.

```
In [1]: x = list(range(28))

In [2]: def by_triples(iterable):
    ...:     it = iter(iterable)
    ...:     triple = tuple(itertools.islice(it, 3))
    ...:     while triple:
    ...:         yield triple
    ...:         triple = tuple(itertools.islice(it, 3))
    ...:
    ...:

In [3]: import itertools

In [4]: for trip in by_triples(x):
    ...:     print(trip)
    ...:
(0, 1, 2)
(3, 4, 5)
(6, 7, 8)
(9, 10, 11)
(12, 13, 14)
(15, 16, 17)
(18, 19, 20)
(21, 22, 23)
(24, 25, 26)
(27,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this alternate solution:

```
def by_n(a_list, n):
    for i in xrange(0, len(a_list), n): 
        yield a_list[i:i+n]

data_train_output = [np.array(_) for _ in by_n(data_train_output_full, 3)]

# or

data_train_output = list(map(np.array, by_n(data_train_output_full, 3))
```